# Avoid undefined in TypedForms in Angular

Tags: angular

I have the following code:

```
  readonly form = new FormGroup({
    summary: new FormControl<string>('', { nonNullable: true, validators: Validators.required }),
    description: new FormControl<string>('', { nonNullable: true, validators: Validators.required }),
  });
```

I have a form with two required fields and nullable is turned off.
Now i have the issue, that the type is still, `string | undefined` instead of `string` if i access `this.form.value.description` before each using and without using `!`.

Any idea how i can achieve this without the need to check each property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution @Eugene provided is not wrong, but we'Ve found another way. It is hard to say if it is the better one.

Instead of `this.form.value` i use `this.form.getRawValue()`.

The reason why the properties in `this.form.value` are potential undefined is that the control could be disabled. In this case no value is provided.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `this.form.value.description` you can use `this.form.controls.description.value`.

Comment: The issue is, that i want to use `this.form.value` as parameter of a function or method and there i want to access `description`. It feels wrong to use `this.form.control`. But we've found a way. `this.form.getRawValue()` is what we want. Not so nice but works for now. Thanks!